# "closed as unclear what you're asking" fully edited after the fifth day. What kind of meta question should I raise?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have made a few edits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550856/my-console-art-is-missing-a-char-is-it-stringbuilder-cwl-or-me) question  but the final full edit was 5 days after. How exactly can I revive my question?

> If you don't get around to editing it within five days, or others
>   don't vote to reopen it in the queue, you should raise a meta question
>   to bring it to everyone's attention so it can get more views that
>   might translate into reopen votes.

Will it help if I spread the question on my own? I feel confident with my English, but can't understand what is meant by "raise a meta question to bring it to everyone's attention".

Comment: Well raising a meta question is exactly what you did here. Opening a question with the point of view of "how can I make my post clearer?" is the best way to go. Btw not sure where the 5 days thing come from honestly

Comment: I have already made my post clearer since I edited it fully. I also know this is raising a meta question I just didn't know what the question should be about.

Comment: Your question's still not particularly clear. Post the complete output the program gives and the complete output that you want (not just a single line of it). Don't read from the console, just hardcode the value. Also, you should probably [reduce your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) more - debug your code to figure out which line is not doing what you want it to do, then remove all the code before it and just hardcode the variables that line needs, then ask a more specific question about how to get whatever you're doing in that line to do what you want.

Comment: *I have made a few edits...* Note that your question only goes to the re-open queue after the **first** edit that's made to it. I don't have enough rep to see if your question is still there but in the future you want to make all necessary edits at once.

Comment: beware the *"meta-effect"*, be very careful with whining or complaining about things it is not met well.

Answer (score 1):

> I just didn't know what the question should be about.

I also don't know where the text you're quoting came from but if you're trying to get a post re-opened then that's what your meta question should be about. That said, I agree with Patrice:

> Opening a question with the point of view of "how can I make my post clearer?" is the best way to go.

Saying, *I've already edited by question but is there anything I've missed or that I can improve?*, is going to go over much better than just, *I've edited my question, can someone re-open it?*. It's the difference between the initial conversation being an argument over whether your question is good enough to be re-opened and simply getting some advice on it if it isn't.